# install missing apps after installing rom?

Tags: installation, restore

I've installed a new ROM. In the previous times I've done this, Play reinstalled them once the phone booted. But this time it didn't (I've tried reinstalling the ROM a second time to make sure).

I have a backup of all these apps in Titanium, but I can't find a feature to install missing apps (just "restore" them, which apparently means just restoring settings & data for those already installed)

Is there anything I can do other than going to 'my apps' in Play and installing them one by one (I have many)?

Answer (score 0):

Titanium should restore the APKs as well as the data.  But another method is to go into Settings>Backup/Restore (or similar), and there is an option for backing up and restoring data from Google Play.

Comment: none of these work

Comment: In that case, you'll probably have to restore one-by-one, manually.  I don't know why Titanium didn't back up APKs.